# Get gcc version number and compare with bash

Tags: bash

I want to check gcc version whether >= 9.1.

First, I type this shell:

```sh
$ gcc --version | grep gcc | awk '{print $3}'
```

I get following in my computer after I type above shell:

```
9.1.0
```

I know bash only can compare number of **integer**,

such as command **"-gt"**.

I want to compare gcc which version >= 9.1 .

How do I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need not to use `grep` with `awk`, `awk` could look for string and could do comparison too. Could you please try following.

```
gcc --version | awk '/gcc/ && ($3+0)>9.1{print "Version is greater than 9.1"}'
```

Comment: Hi RavinderSingh13: Please add \"\ last \greater than 9.1\

Comment: after added, this command work normal

Comment: @curlywei, Thanks for letting me know, when I checked I haven't seen a `"` but no issues as per your suggestion I changed from `$3` to `$3+0`, kindly check it once and let me know?

Comment: Hi: Before add \"\ last \greater than 9.1 add \"\, command report me error message: https://imgur.com/egEOCzo

Comment: After added https://imgur.com/kxn91RH

Comment: @curlywei, sure, feel free to edit my answer too, so that others could be benefited.

Comment: I try to edit, but when I save change, I get this error message  of edit: Edits must be at least 6 characters; is there something else to improve in this post?

Comment: @curlywei, add some text details in it and it should be fine :)